# selected value of f..select lost after page refresh in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a dropdown in ruby on rails i.e below:

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td align="center">
      <%= f.select(:Interest,options_from_collection_for_select(@students, "id", "student_mentor_subjects"), {},:id => "DDL_Students", :style => "width:160px;") %>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And students is a table that are populating `f.select` and below is the schema of students table:

```
id | student_mentor_subjects
1  | ijk
2  | mno
3  | pqr
```

And when I select a value from above `f.select` and click on search button then page is refresh and the selected value is lost, How could I retain the selected value of `f.select` after page refresh.
Kindly help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From the api:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select

`options_from_collection_for_select(collection, value_method, text_method, selected = nil)`

The fourth argument to options_from_collection_for_select is the default value.  In your case you need to set it from params, then fall back to a specific default if there's nothing in params for it (which would be the case when you load the page for the first time).

I don't know which value to read from params as you've not posted the rest of the form, but if you look in your log you should see which value you want to read.  So, it **might** be something like

```
      <%= f.select(:Interest,options_from_collection_for_select(@students, "id", "student_mentor_subjects", params[:search][:interest] || @students.first.id), {},:id => "DDL_Students", :style => "width:160px;") %>
```

Comment: It give me an error "can't convert Symbol into Integer"

Comment: I did say that was just an example: you haven't posted what is stored in @students or what your params are.

Comment: What about your params?  Look in your server log for these.

Comment: nothing in params because I am getting an error "can't convert Symbol into Integer". I don't understand, how do I resolve it.

Comment: Look in your server log.  Find the stack trace for the exception.  Paste it into your original post.  Then scroll up till you find the line listing the controller name and action being called.  Something like this (an example from my log): `Processing ContentController#lesson [GET]
Parameters: {"modules"=>["1270-fs-ks1", "134982-nursery-rhymes"], "lesson_id"=>"64214-Baa-Baa-Black-Sheep"}`.  What is in Parameters?  Paste that into your OP too.